# Audio recording?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Can i record audio without using a communication server in flash?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question means that you just don't want to use "Flash Communication Server" or just any communication server in general. If you are just looking for an alternative to Flash Communication Server you can use the free Red5 Media Server instead: http://www.red5.org/

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here is one library which will make your work much easier: http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/
I don't believe you can record everything automatically, the user has to allow access to his microphone and save the file. But it works.

Comment: Good catch. This library makes uses of the flash.media.Microphone package. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Microphone.html

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, answer can be found in this thread  [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704852/how-do-i-embed-a-flash-audio-recorder-in-my-site/6707803#6707803)